# A quick method of calculating rolling standard deviation of matrix in R

Tags: r

I would like to find a quick method to calculate rolling standard deviation of a matrix. To be precise in explaining what I mean, I have mocked up some code below to show exactly what I am looking for. This as you know will be very slow

```
aaa <- matrix(1:1000,10,100)
bbb <- aaa
bbb[] <- NA
tt.n <- 5

for (i in (tt.n:dim(aaa)[2]))
    {
    bbb[,i] <- apply(aaa[,(i-tt.n+1):i],1,sd)   
    }
```

Comment: See `rollapply` in the zoo package.